# pyspark- elif statement and assign position to extract a value

Tags: dataframe, if-statement, pyspark, position

I have a dataframe like the example

| productNo | prodcuctMT | productPR | productList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2389 | ['xy-5', 'yz-12','zb-56','iu-30'] | ['pr-1', 'pr-2', 'pr-3', 'pr-4'] | ['67230','7839','1339','9793'] |
| 6745 | ['xy-4', 'yz-34','zb-8','iu-9'] | ['pr-6', pr-1', 'pr-3', 'pr-7'] | ['1111','0987','8910','0348'] |

I would like to use elif statement for multiple conditions where we look at productMT and if it passes the condition it looks at productPR and takes the position for which it satisfies the condition.

if productMT contains xy-5 then if productPR contains pr-1 , take its position and add new column with value from productList.

| productNo | prodcuctMT | productPR | productList | productList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2389 | ['xy-5', 'yz-12','zb-56','iu-30'] | ['pr-1', 'pr-2', 'pr-3', 'pr-4'] | ['67230','7839','1339','9793'] | 67230 |

I tried using a filter but it only does the work for one filter and I need to run on multiple filters so it loops through all rows and conditions.

````
    F.arrays_zip('productList', 'prodcuctMT', 'productPR'),
    lambda x: (x.prodcuctMT == 'xy-5') & (x.productPR != 'pr-1')
)
df_array_pos = df_array.withColumn('output', filtered[0].productList).withColumn('flag',  filtered[0].prodcuctMT)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use multiple `when` functions for each elif conditions you want

Your sample data

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2389, ['xy-5', 'yz-12','zb-56','iu-30'], ['pr-1', 'pr-2', 'pr-3', 'pr-4'], ['67230','7839','1339','9793']),
    (6745, ['xy-4', 'yz-34','zb-8','iu-9'], ['pr-6', 'pr-1', 'pr-3', 'pr-7'], ['1111','0987','8910','0348']),
], ['productNo', 'productMT', 'productPR', 'productList'])

+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+
|productNo|productMT                  |productPR               |productList              |
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+
|2389     |[xy-5, yz-12, zb-56, iu-30]|[pr-1, pr-2, pr-3, pr-4]|[67230, 7839, 1339, 9793]|
|6745     |[xy-4, yz-34, zb-8, iu-9]  |[pr-6, pr-1, pr-3, pr-7]|[1111, 0987, 8910, 0348] |
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+
```

You can add as many `when` as you like

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('output', F
        .when(F.array_contains('productMT', 'xy-5') & F.array_contains('productPR', 'pr-1'), F.col('productList')[F.array_position('productMT', 'xy-5') - 1])
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+------+
|productNo|productMT                  |productPR               |productList              |output|
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+------+
|2389     |[xy-5, yz-12, zb-56, iu-30]|[pr-1, pr-2, pr-3, pr-4]|[67230, 7839, 1339, 9793]|67230 |
|6745     |[xy-4, yz-34, zb-8, iu-9]  |[pr-6, pr-1, pr-3, pr-7]|[1111, 0987, 8910, 0348] |null  |
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+------+
```

Comment: thanks @pltc
what if I want to select if element has part of the txt like `F.array_contains('productPR', 'pr-1') ====> F.array_contains('productPR', 'pr')`

Comment: I'm afraid it's not an option. The closest hacking solution I can think about is casting your `productPR` to a string and try [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract), but it is, of course, not safe and have edge cases you have to take care

Comment: I see. what if i just write elif statement(like how we do in python) and keep it in a function, maybe UDF, and pass it through data frame? does it make sence? 
thanks for help

Comment: UDF performance is much worse than Spark's built-in functions, so you should try to avoid it as much as possible.